# How to set clipboard hook with hidden WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

I'm trying to place clipboard hook with SetClipboardViewer method on user32.dll

```
 [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
 public static extern IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr hWndNewViewer);
```

I then override the WndProc method on the form to catch the messages:

```
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
        switch ((User32Handler.SystemMessages)message.Msg)
        {
            case User32Handler.SystemMessages.WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:

                if (MainForm.isFirstCopyPaste)
                {
                    MainForm.isFirstCopyPaste = false;
                    return;
                }

                var data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
                {
                    NotifyIconMain.ShowBalloonTip(2000, "Text Copied", "Plain text copied", ToolTipIcon.Info);
                }


                User32Handler.SendMessage(_nextClipboardViewer, message.Msg, message.WParam, message.LParam);
                break;
            case User32Handler.SystemMessages.WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
                Debug.WriteLine("WM_CHANGECBCHAIN: lParam: " + message.LParam, "WndProc");
                if (message.WParam == _nextClipboardViewer)
                {
                    _nextClipboardViewer = message.LParam;
                }
                else
                {
                    User32Handler.SendMessage(_nextClipboardViewer, message.Msg, message.WParam, message.LParam);
                }
                break;
            default:
                base.WndProc(ref message);
                break;
        }
    }
```

I was able to achieve this, but I also want to hide the window from the user and also show it only on system tray, (not on taskbar).

The moment I hide the window from the task bar the hook stops working. It even does not work when I bring the window back again.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: where are you initializing the hook?

Comment: in the form load event

Comment: @Dimkin - If your application is minimized then its not possible to capture the clipboard because your application is running in the background.  A Service would be able to do this of course.

Comment: How are you "hiding" the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that whatever you're doing to hide the window is not destroying it.  Your window handle has to be the same number, from application start to terminate.  So a little debug logging should tell  you if you've got the same handle after restoring from the tray, that you originally started with (and subsequently registered).

Comment: Yup.  Like changing the ShowInTaskbar property.  This kind of code must always be done by overriding OnHandleCreated(), not OnLoad().